# for in loop in jscript object is displayed as text

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```
        var Product = {
            name : 'Soap',
            brand : 'Dove',
            price : 25.50,
            discountRate : 5,
            quantitySold: [10,5,25,8,4],
            netPrice:function(){return this.price * (100 - this.discountRate) / 100;},
            averageSales:function(){
                for(var sum in this.quantitySold){
                    var i = 0;
                    i++
                    sum += this.quantitySold[i];
                }
                return sum
            }
        }
```

the code is supposed to add the values in the array (quantitySold) then average them, but i can't seem to display that for in loop, when you run the code it only displays as a text

Comment: if you are using `for-in` then sum will be index of array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add all numbers in the array, and then divide them by the length of the array. [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) is a nice way to loop and sum the data:

```js
var Product = {
  name: 'Soap',
  brand: 'Dove',
  price: 25.50,
  discountRate: 5,
  quantitySold: [10, 5, 25, 8, 4],
  netPrice: function() {
    return this.price * (100 - this.discountRate) / 100;
  },
  averageSales: function() {
    return this.quantitySold.length && this.quantitySold.reduce(function(sum, num) {
      return sum + num;
    }) / this.quantitySold.length;
  }
}

console.log(Product.averageSales());
```

If you wish to use a simple loop go with the simple [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```js
var Product = {
  name: 'Soap',
  brand: 'Dove',
  price: 25.50,
  discountRate: 5,
  quantitySold: [10, 5, 25, 8, 4],
  netPrice: function() {
    return this.price * (100 - this.discountRate) / 100;
  },
  averageSales: function() {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.quantitySold.length; i++) {
      sum += this.quantitySold[i];
    }

    return sum / this.quantitySold.length;
  }
}

console.log(Product.averageSales());
```

**Why the result of your code is "45"?**

When you're using [`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), the `sum` variable holds the property key string (the index), and everything is discarded when it recieves a new index. In addition, on each loop you reset `i` to 0, and increment it by 1, so `i` effectivly is always 1. When it reaches the last iteration `sum` is `"4"`, the number in index `1` is 5 => `"4" + 5 === "45"`, and this is the result you get.

Comment: you should tell what is problem in op's code why it's not working .just don't give your opinion .

Comment: @Mahi - added the description of the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var Product = {
            name : 'Soap',
            brand : 'Dove',
            price : 25.50,
            discountRate : 5,
            quantitySold: [10,5,25,8,4],
            netPrice:function(){return this.price * (100 - this.discountRate) / 100;},
            averageSales:function(){
                var sum = 0;
                for(var i in this.quantitySold){
                    sum += this.quantitySold[i];
                }
                return (sum / this.quantitySold.length);
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks, i tried that code and i thought it didn't work then i had a mistake in displaying it XD, instead of Product.averageSales(), i typed Product.averageSales. anyways thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `for..in` loop with the array which should be used for `object`. You can use a regular `for` loop as below.

```js
var Product = {
                name : 'Soap',
                brand : 'Dove',
                price : 25.50,
                discountRate : 5,
                quantitySold: [10,5,25,8,4],
                netPrice: function(){ return this.price * (100 - this.discountRate) / 100; },
                averageSales: function(){
                    var sum = 0;
                    for(var i = 0; i < this.quantitySold.length; i++){
                        sum += this.quantitySold[i];
                    }
                    return sum / this.quantitySold.length;
                }
            };

console.log(Product.averageSales());
```

Answer (score 0):

I that for... in is setting `sum` value as `this.quantitySold` properties name, but an equivalent way to do your desired loop is to declare a for... of (which was for... each in ES4) which iterates over collections. Of course you should declare `sum` initializing with `0` in a place its value won't be affected. Since we're going to use for...of we can only declare `sum` outside its parens because of the syntaxes. If it was a common for we could declare it inside: `for (var ..., sum = 0;;)`

```
sum = 0;

for (let quantity of this.quantitySold)
    sum += quantity;

var sum;
return sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Product = {
    name : 'Soap',
    brand : 'Dove',
    price : 25.50,
    discountRate : 5,
    quantitySold: [10, 5, 25, 8, 4],
    netPrice: function(){ 
        return this.price * (100 - this.discountRate) / 100;
    },
    findAverage: function() {
    // create a var for the quantitySold Array
    var quantity = Product.quantitySold;

    // find the sum of each item in the Array using reduce
    var sum = quantity.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return (a + b);
    });

    // take the average of the sum divided by the number of items in the Array
    return avg = sum / quantity.length;
  }
}

// Run the function to return the avg
Product.findAverage();
```

It would also be better to create a function that takes in an object as the first argument and a function that runs this findAverage code as the second argument. That way you can run it on any object so it's reusable.